# Get max user scores from hourly sums

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, sum

I have a MySql table with sample data like this:

```
+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+
|      id | user_id | scores |          created_at |
+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+
|       1 |       1 |     10 | 2012-12-14 02:40:37 |
|       2 |       1 |     20 | 2012-12-14 02:55:54 |
|       3 |       1 |     10 | 2012-12-14 01:17:21 |
|       4 |       2 |     30 | 2012-12-13 01:54:47 |
|       5 |       2 |     55 | 2012-12-15 00:34:39 |
|       6 |       2 |     10 | 2012-12-14 00:20:21 |
+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

And I need to query it, so that scores would be summed per user and per hour. One hour here is assumed to be `created_at` with skipped minutes and seconds (04:00:00 to 04:59:59 etc.). So something like this:

```
+---------+--------+---------------------+
| user_id | scores |          created_at |
+---------+--------+---------------------+
|       1 |     30 | 2012-12-14 02:00:00 |
|       1 |     10 | 2012-12-14 01:00:00 |
|       2 |     30 | 2012-12-13 01:00:00 |
|       2 |     55 | 2012-12-15 00:00:00 |
|       2 |     10 | 2012-12-14 00:00:00 |
+---------+--------+---------------------+
```

In this sample data only first user played more than once during one hour (2012-12-14 02:00:00) - so his scores during that hour were summed up.

From summed scores I need only top score for each user (to create ranks). So final, expected result should be:

```
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| user_id | top_scores_per_hour |                hour |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|       1 |                  30 | 2012-12-14 02:00:00 |
|       2 |                  55 | 2012-12-15 00:00:00 |
+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I have an Idea how to do part of this... I could deal with rest outside of database, but I really wonder - how could I query this with SQL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.user_id,
       a.totalScores top_scores_per_hour,
       a.newTime hour
FROM
    (
      SELECT  user_id, 
              SUM(Scores) totalScores, 
              DATE_Format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') newTime
      FROM    TableName 
      GROUP BY user_id, DATE_Format(created_at, '%y-%m-%d %H:00:00')
    ) a INNER JOIN 
    (
      SELECT  user_id, 
              max(DATE_Format(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00')) newTime
      FROM    TableName 
      GROUP BY user_ID
    ) b ON a.user_ID = b.user_ID AND
           a.newTime = b.newTime
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5cd1/4)

Output

```
╔═════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ USER_ID ║ TOP_SCORES_PER_HOUR ║        HOUR         ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║       1 ║                  30 ║ 2012-12-14 02:00:00 ║
║       2 ║                  55 ║ 2012-12-15 00:00:00 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: Sorry, I unaccepted after using it with more data. It always picks newest hour with scores sum, instead of picking hour with highest scores sum.

Comment: The comment is the actuall answer for my needs. I would accept it instead if I could, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT user_id, score, createdDate 
FROM (SELECT user_id, SUM(scores) score, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d %H:00:00') createdDate 
      FROM tablename 
      GROUP BY user_id, createdDate
      ORDER BY user_id, score DESC) AS A 
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: This also works, and looks much simplier. I'am worried however about safety - will the results always match expected. Because there is no guarantee, that non-grouped column will always be used from last group row, right? I've picked other answer, but this one is good too. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Select user_id, Max(totalHouirlyScore) TopHourlyScore
From (Select user_id, Sum(scores) totalHouirlyScore
      From tablename
      Group By user_id, 
            DateFormat(created_at, '%y%m%d%H')) Z
```

Comment: The problem is I need also the hour column :(

Comment: can't you just add `DateFormat(created_at, '%y%m%d%H')) Z` to the list of select columns then?

Comment: Greg - nope. Besides running this query even without hour column doesn't return expected data.